# How to Restoring MySQL database from physical files

Tags: mysql, xampp, restore

Unfortunately I uninstalled Xampp in my windows machine, there are about 50 databases in /xamp/mysql/data folder. I have not taken backup script, but I have a copy of Xamp/mysql/data folder.How can I restore MySQL Databases using that Data Directory.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8):

I was find out solution

1. Install new xampp
2. Copy your old database folder from
   xampp\mysql\data\databasefolder to Paste in your running xampp folder
   C:\xampp\mysql\data
3. After that stop mysql and apache service then backup your running xampp files ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1 and ibdata1 and store in safe place
4. Then Copy same file (ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1 and ibdata1) from old 
   xampp\mysql\data\ and paste in your running xampp server C:\xampp\mysql\data\
5. Start mysql and apache service Open CMD Fire command 
   C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -u dbusername -p dbpassword dbname>D:\exportdb.sql
6. stop mysql and apache service and restore your main ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1 and ibdata1 file (check Step 3)
7. after than again start service and open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ and import database backup from D:\exportdb.sql 
   Now your backup is working :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul, great solution!

Comment: Marvelous working solution! Just a note please export exportdb.sql file to any folder in drive C: as sometimes no drive D: is available :) Also you may zip the database.sql file if large enough for easy import through phpmyadmin as max file size is 40MiB

Answer (score 1):

Install the same Server version again, Stop it , copy the datadir and Start the servrr

Comment: Hi Bernd,
Thanks for reply I have done as you suggested, but when I tried to start mysql in Xamp getting this error
'1:18:33 PM  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
1:18:33 PM  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:18:33 PM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:18:33 PM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:18:33 PM  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:18:33 PM  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
1:18:33 PM  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums'

Comment: do you also have the same my.cnf ?

Comment: No, I have only Data folder

Answer (score 1):

I experienced with my Mac, before selling to a friend simply copy the XAMPP folder only to my hard drive.
(NOT SUCCESS) Unfortunately, it was bringing trouble to me, because I tried the following steps:
- I install fresh XAMPP and copy the whole \httdocs and var\mysql to my new Mac, those db only with .frm and .ibd, NOT WORKING, I can't still access the tables inside PHPMyAdmin ...
- I tried to install the same xampp version and repeat the above steps, still NOT WORKING.
- Decided to go to bed.

(SUCCESS)
- This morning, I brought my backup disk and try with Windows 7.
- Install fresh latest XAMPP for Windows, c:\xampp
- I have one of website (folder) from my backup \httdocs and correspond database folder inside \var\mysql are READY in my windows 7, I just want to try with one website then try the rest because I have many projects inside httdocs\ and \var\mysql
- I copy the mention httdocs\ folder to windows c:\xampp\httdocs and copy the \var\mysql to c:\xampp\mysql\data

NOT LAST YET
I copy the ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1 from my backup file to windows xampp c:\xampp\mysql\data

I refresh the http://localhost/mywebsite

WOW WOW DONE ... it's working...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found pretty straight solution.

I had db files in wamp and ported to laragon

1. Stopped laragon instance, no apache/mysql was running.
2. I have simply copied db folder[dbname] "example /mysql/data/dbname" from wamp to laragon "/mysql/data/" folder

Than I started my laragon instance both apache/mysql.

I have checked in phpmyadmin, I can see same database was recovered and now part of current mysql database.