# MySQL add an old database to newly installed server

Tags: mysql, database, data-migration

I uninstalled my old WAMP server and installed a new. I forgot to make a backup of the old database but the database is still there on the old installation directory.
I read somewhere that it would be possible to just copy the folder containing the database to the new data directory. It worked to a part. I can connect to the database and show all tables. But if I want to access the tables e.g. do a select, it say's the table does not exist.

What can I do in this situation? Export is no longer an option for me as I no longer can access the database.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041976/recovering-mysql-database-from-data-folder-backup

Comment: No, MySQL does not start. I renamed the datafolder and copied the old data folder and then tried to start mysql.

Comment: I fear that this question cannot end well, because you're going to encounter dubious or ambiguous advice.  Stop what you are doing and focus on obtaining a restorable dump of the old data, not trying to recover it or merge it into the reinstalled system.  Were the tables InnoDB, as they should have been? If so, *do not copy, move, or rename anything* because the results can only be bad.  Please advise: InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Probably InnoDB, theres a file named IBData1. The old version is 5.6.17 and the new one is 5.7.14. I thinka I have to reinstall the old version, but how can I do that now?