# Restore SQL database from backup of "C:\xampp\mysql\data" folder

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Recently my laptop crashed and while making a backup of the XAMPP instead of taking a backup of the entire XAMPP folder I just copied the

> "C:\xampp\mysql\data"

folder.
Now I am trying to restore the old database, the issue is if I try to just paste the folder of the database (Eg database folder named 'X123' - it cotains both ibd and frm files), then X123 shows up in PHPMyadmin but doesn't work as when I click on the table it says 'table doesnt exist'. I read other answers which suggested that I also replace the following files

```
ibdata1, ib_logfile1, ib_logfile0
```

When I try to do the same, MySQL simply stops working.

I have tried fixing the errors after reading some of the related answers here by importing the `create_tables.sql` file from `"C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\examples"` and some other stuff but nothing seems to work.

I would really appreciate if you can guide me as to what would be the best way to restore this data on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution on another answer at stackoverflow. Apologies for double post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46970116/9879647

In my case I also had to edit php.ini so as to increase the max execution time as well as file size that can be imported.