# Rebuilding a MySQL database after reinstalling XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, repair

**EDIT:** Nbk suggested [stackoverflow.com/a/46970116/5193536](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46970116/5193536) which looked pretty good if I had not accidentally deleted one of the relevant files!

=========================================================================

I am on day 2 after my main notebook died. Installed XAMPP on a spare machine and all working until suddenly XAMPP refused to run MySQL. Tried various things then admitted defeat and installed new version XAMPP.

I found this [migrating MySQL](https://developpaper.com/steps-to-reinstall-xampp-and-migrate-mysql-data-under-windows/) guide and thought it might work but copying over the  `ib_logfile 0` or  `ibdata1` caused the start up to fail.

I still have the folder of my database available but these control files will not gel.

Is there any way of rebuilding from just the folder in the `mysql\data` directory? I expect not.

If not it was a pretty small DB so should take less than 90 mins to rebuild. But, having spent well over 4 hours reinstalling reconfiguring and trying to repair I would just like to see if I can fix the bloomin thing!

Comment: try this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/46970116/5193536

Comment: NBK thanks looks like a good steer... but sadly managed to delete the ib_logfile 0 BUT because I am pretty anal about name compliance rebuilt the DB in 38 mins. It occurs to me just now that I should have said that I did not care about data recovery. The DB only has five tables with about 45 columns. Bit of judicious cut and past and voila! I really need to sort out backup I think.