# How to properly restore data from an old XAMPP data backup

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed XAMPP on my PC and been working for ages on a project that I was just about to wind up. A few days ago, I tried to rename one of the databases but ended up with a database connection error. I made a backup of the entire XAMPP folder but been unsuccessful on the restoration, 5 days now and I'm panic-stricken. I deleted the new data folder and replaced with the old data folder but still in vain.

I have the same version of XAMPP for the old and new installations. Also, I stopped Apache and MySQL first before replacing the data folder.

The database tables are present but the data is missing. When I click the table, I get an error - `#1932 - Table 'north.wp_terms' doesn't exist in engine`. I am literally at crossroads at this point. I am quite frankly new to XAMPP I would have been more careful. I can upload the required files online for troubleshooting, if requested.

Comment: check this Question answers
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041976/recovering-mysql-database-from-data-folder-backup)

Comment: Hi, I followed the procedure above. The tables are there. No data. When I open one of the tables, I get this error - #1932 - Table 'group.wp_frm_fields' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: i add add link to old subject , i hope you find what you need [recovering-mysql-database-from-data-folder-backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041976/recovering-mysql-database-from-data-folder-backup)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Followed the procedures keenly but I can't quite understand why the data won't show up. The tables are however present.

Comment: I have one ```arial_log.00000001``` file and several ```mysql-relay-bin``` , ```relay-log ``` files in my data folder. How useful are towards restoring the database?

Comment: I also have a backup of the entire website but the one I lost was an extended version (Had some work done on it). Do you think it could be helpful for restoring table structures and possible the data? *I wish someone told me this recovery is not possible because I still continue to push regardless of several failed attempts.