# How to perfom an sql dump from cmd to export database from old xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to restore a database from old xampp folder. I am following this procedure highlighted here by Rahul Shewale [edited by Ahmad Baktash] The process goes smoothly but I am stuck at step 5 [LINK TO PROCEDURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041976/recovering-mysql-database-from-data-folder-backup)

...
5. Start mysql and apache service Open CMD Fire command C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -u dbusername -p dbpassword dbname>D:\exportdb.sql
...

I am running this command in CMD

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -u root -p group>exportdb.sql
```

The Error: `1932: "Table'group.wp_actionscheduler_actions' doesn't exist in engine"` when using LOCK TABLES

Any help will do.