# INFORMATION SCHEMA MYSQL DATABASES DELETED

Tags: mysql

Help I deleted my information schema database I'm trying to recover it and get the size of the database that I create. Can someone please help me?

I thought that it was an example database so I clear some of the databases.

Comment: Do you have a backup? If not you're probably stuck with a reinstallation.

Comment: If you using you using `XAMPP`, please refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31649197/12715723

Comment: If you only want the 'size' of a db you've created, you could try looking up the database files. On my Ubuntu they're located at /var/lib/mysql/[dbname]/...